# Unable to read html_basic.tld from jsf-impl-2.1.2.jar

Tags: jsf, servlets, tomcat7

I deployed my app in Tomcat7 with jsf 2.1.2, while accessing my jsp page I am getting an IOException

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /login.jsp (line: 4, column: 56) Unable to read TLD "META-INF/html_basic.tld" from JAR file "jndi:/localhost/AdminUI/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.1.2.jar": java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
```

but the needed file is present inside the JAR under META-INF. Is this a jsf bug?

Comment: No, this is not a JSF bug. This is an environmental bug. I however wonder if it works if you use JSP's successor Facelets instead of legacy JSP.

Comment: What to do BalusC? How to recover from this? I want to work with JSF.

Comment: Too many possible causes. Classpath pollution is one of them and not uncommon among starters. Truly you can keep using JSF when you use JSP's successor Facelets as view technology. Even more, it's the **recommended** and **default** view technology of JSF 2.x. JSP has been deprecated as JSF 2.x view technology. See also http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html Just give Facelets a try.

Comment: Thanks Balusc, the provided link helps a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Tomcat is bundled with few api's like servlet-api, jsp-api which might be causing conflicts. So i suggest deploying the application with empty lib and add libraries based on the error logs (i mean the deployment errors not the compilation error) so this way you are sure that you add right libraries.

Note: some libraries are required for compilation and not for deployment purpose since the server is already packed with those!

I had the same issue which i solved by having only jsf-api, jsf-impl,jstl-x and log4j.x (in my case)